# Fine grained access with dynamoDB and user groups

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cognito, amazon-iam

I am trying to setup a web application using aws Amplify. It is backed by a dynamodb table containing some data, with "user group" as primary key. So whenever a user is logged, it should only display data connected to his group. I read some aws docs about fine-grained access, but it seems that the only way is to use "user_id" as primary key (hopefully i misunderstood that). If any of you could give me some tips i would be very thankful :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you are trying to apply some sort of row isolation strategy on your dynamo table.

Your intuition about the primary key is right as stated [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/apn/partitioning-pooled-multi-tenant-saas-data-with-amazon-dynamodb/) with the caveat that your partition key should **contain** your **group**_id (not necessarily the user_id) since you want to isolate access by groups.

Using composite partition keys is [common practice](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/choosing-the-right-dynamodb-partition-key/) in a database like Dynamo.

This will structure the DB so that it can be restricted by a IAM policy that allows for the [fine grained access control](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/specifying-conditions.html) on the groups that you need.

Comment: Thank you! I managed to get the user's group in my app as an array of strings, now I just need to create a page for each line of my DynamoDB table, but I think i will open a new discussion since it is not strictly related.

Comment: (Ti ringrazio e credo di aver selezionato la tua risposta come risposta corretta, correggimi se sbaglio)